# xcode 12 + Swift + UIImageView

Tags: swift, uiimageview, swift5, xcode12

Since I have opened my project with xcode 12 I am getting the following issue:

```
import UIKit

class PersonViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  
  let imageView = UIImageView()
  let carImage = UIImage(named: "carImg")
  imageView.image = carImage
}
}
```

The error I am getting is: "No exact matches in reference to instance method 'image"
The compiler is basically not recognising that UIImageView has a property called "image" or that UIKit is not imported.

If I create a new project this compiles just fine, so I am guessing it is some sort of setting that was fine in xcode11 but not fine in xcode12.

**Note**: This is an Objective C project with a few classes in Swift.

**Note**: Restarted my mac, did clean project and removed Derived Data

Comment: If everything looks fine: Restart Xcode, restart the Mac. Xcode is just a program with bugs. This is very sad to say and used to be the Top-1-solution for MS Windows, but unfortunatly, Mac and Xcode are catching up rapidly.

Comment: I would also add a Clean project step in there, sometimes that does the trick.

Answer (score -3):

Are you missing an import of UIKit at the top of your file?

```
import UIKit

class PersonViewController: UIViewController {

    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      
      let imageView = UIImageView()
      let carImage = UIImage(named: "carImg")
      imageView.image = carImage
    }
}
```

Comment: this is not related with IBOutlet. The code should simply compile without any IBOutlet. It works fine in a fresh project

Comment: Oh, sorry. That will teach me to try to reply without looking at the question carfefully. Nevermind.

Answer (score -4):

class PersonViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView! //This line is important and must not be excluded
```

Comment: You should explain your answer, not just give code (even if it does work)